# Android nested mapView within scrollView not firing event

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-mapview

I was having some problem when trying to scroll the mapView located inside the scrollView in Android programming. Here is my XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<com.esri.android.map.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapBlock"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            initExtent="21801.3, 25801.0, 33218.7, 44830.0" >
        </com.esri.android.map.MapView>
</ScrollView>
```

And inside my onCreate():

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) eventChart.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
mMapViewBlock = (MapView) eventChart.findViewById(R.id.mapBlock);
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            eventChart.findViewById(R.id.scrollView).getParent()
                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
    mMapViewBlock.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

However, with these code, when my map is onClick, the scroll view did disabled but I could not zoom in/out or navigate around the map. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you happen to resolve this? I have the similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245821/google-map-view-fragment-inside-nestedscrollview-scroll-on-map-fragment-not-pro

Comment: got any solution for this!